# How to identify the report Items in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I'm new to SSRS and unbale to find out the report items used in exiting SSRS report.I would like to know how can I indentify the Report item type wether it's List or Table. Is there any property exists in ssrs to identify the Type?

Comment: I suggest you open up the .RDL file in a text editor like VS Code and take a look

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for reply. Is there any specific property name which should I look? I can see below property but  it is not showing the details wether it's List or Table 
<ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix1">

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-rdl/53287204-7cd0-4bc9-a5cd-d42a5925dca1 is a link to the official spec. If you can't identify a difference between List and Table items in RDL, then they must be the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the object can be viewed and edited in the Properties window. Right-click on an object and select Properties to see this popup.

[image]

When you select an object, its name is also displayed at the top of the properties section. You can also use this dropdown to select any object in the report.

[image]

Note that you should be using the "SQL Server Data Tools" module in Visual Studio to see these properties. If you don't see the properties section, you can enable it from the `View` menu by selecting `Properties Window`.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, is there any way to get the item detials if Name of item is changed from default.

Comment: @KD29 Not sure what you mean. The item name is visible in the properties regardless of if it has been changed or not. What details are you looking for? And how would you identify which item you're looking for?